# Large Scale Image Classifier

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I have a large set of plant images labeled with the botanical name. What would be the best algorithm to use to train on this dataset in order to classify an unlabel photo? The photos are processed so that 100% of the pixels contain the plant (e.g. either closeups of the leaves or bark), so there are no other objects/empty-space/background that the algorithm would have to filter out.

I've already tried generating [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) features for all the photos and feeding these (feature,label) pairs to a [LibLinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) SVM, but the accuracy was a miserable 6%.

I also tried feeding this same data to a few [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) classifiers. The accuracy was a little better (25% with Logistic, 18% with IBk), but Weka's not designed for scalability (it loads everything into memory). Since the SIFT feature dataset is a several million rows, I could only test Weka with a random 3% slice, so it's probably not representative.

EDIT: Some sample images:

[image: Pachira aquatica]
[image: Fagus grandifolia]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, you would not train on the SIFT features directly. Cluster them (using k-means) and then train on the histogram of cluster membership identifiers (i.e., a k-dimensional vector, which counts, at position *i*, how many features were assigned to the *i*-th cluster).

This way, you obtain a single output per image (and a single, k-dimensional, feature vector).

Here's the quasi-code (using [mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas) and [milk](http://luispedro.org/software/milk) in Pythonn):

```
from mahotas.surf import surf
from milk.unsupervised.kmeans import kmeans,assign_centroids
import milk

# First load your data:
images = ...
labels = ...

local_features = [surfs(im, 6, 4, 2) for im in imgs]
allfeatures = np.concatenate(local_features)
_, centroids = kmeans(allfeatures, k=100)
histograms = []
for ls in local_features:
     hist = assign_centroids(ls, centroids, histogram=True)
     histograms.append(hist)

cmatrix, _ = milk.nfoldcrossvalidation(histograms, labels)
print "Accuracy:", (100*cmatrix.trace())/cmatrix.sum()
```

Comment: What do you mean by histogram of cluster membership identifiers?

Comment: Is there a general rule-of-thumb when selecting a K? I was going to start with K=100. Is that too high?

Comment: No, there is on rule of thumb. It doesn't matter that much generally. K=100 seems ok.

Comment: Thanks, the code clarifies it perfectly. Also, great job developing Mahotas. I'm finding it to be a very useful image processing library.

Comment: Update on the rule-of-thumb when selecting K, on a paper in 2013, we showed that K=4/n (n being the number of points) was a good heuristic on our data: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/29/18/2343.short

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly hard problem.

You can give [BoW model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model_in_computer_vision) a try.

Basically, you extract SIFT features on all the images, then use K-means to cluster the features into visual words. After that, use the BoW vector to train you classifiers.

See the Wikipedia article above and the references papers in that for more details.

Comment: I believe this is essentially the same approach mentioned by luispedro, although the BoW terminology is a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need better alignment, and probably not more features. There is no way you can get acceptable performance unless you have correspondences. You need to know what points in one leaf correspond to points on another leaf. This is one of the "holy grail" problems in computer vision.

People have used [shape context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context) for this problem. You should probably look at [this link](http://leafsnap.com/). [This paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~belhumeur/conference/eccv08b.pdf) describes the basic system behind leafsnap.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "better alignment"? Shape context seems more applicable to simple outlines and images with clearly defined geometry (e.g. logos/letters/numbers). Not the kind of noisy jumbles of shapes present in my images. However, the Leafsnap project is interesting, and appears to be exactly like what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, their site doesn't actually do any classification and makes no mention of what technologies they've used to successfully classify images.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the BoW model according to this [Bag-of-Features Descriptor on SIFT Features with OpenCV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O). It is a very good tutorial to implement the BoW model in OpenCV.