# Image classification using SIFT and SVM with Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I have some images of flowers that I have extracted SIFT features from and I clustered the features using K-Means(k=3). I would like to create a "histogram of cluster membership identifiers" to feed to an SVM classifier as described in the accepted answer to the question below.

[Large Scale Image Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703013/large-scale-image-classifier)

My question is, how do I create this histogram in Java? I'm using OpenCV, is there a method I have missed?

I have a Mat of centres where each row is a cluster centre and I have a Mat of labels where each element in a column is a cluster index (0...2) for each key point in an image.

Comment: For those ending up here, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32017448/3079302) should help.